# How do I derive the Bubble Sort Comparison Formula?

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort

So I'm in high school learning about sorting algorithms, and we've analyzed Bubble Sort recently.

My teacher showed the formula to find the number of comparisons (C) it takes Bubble Sort to sort a certain number of items (n)

So the equation is:

> C = (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1
>
> > = [n(n-1)]/2

The only thing I'm a little confused about is how you derive:

> C = [n(n-1)]/2

from

> C = (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1

I know this is most likely pretty basic math, but I just can't figure it out. I've searched online but they don't really show a step-by-step of how exactly to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Its just the sum upto `n` elements in Arithmetic Progression with a difference of 1, given by : `n*(n+1)/2`. So from 1 to n-1 elements you have `(n-1)*(n-1+1)/2 = n(n-1)/2`.

Look up : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression for the general formula of an Arithmetic Progression.

Another way to solve this:

`S = 1 + 2 + .... + (n-1)` ... `[Eq 1]`

Writing backwards:

`S = (n-1) + (n-2) + ... +2 + 1` ....`[Eq 2]`

Adding Eq (1) and (2) we have:

`2S = n + n .... upto (n-1) terms`

Finally:

`S = [n*(n-1)]/2`

Comment: Thanks! After seeing your second method I think I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three ways to approach it.

By staring at it until you see the pattern:

```
n   C
1   0
2   1
3   3
4   6
5  10
.   .
.   .
.   .
```

Geometrically, by seeing that it's half of a rectangle:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Algebraically, by rearranging elements:

```
C = (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 
  = [(n-1)+1] + [(n-2)+2] + [(n-3)+3] + ...
  = n + n + n + ...
```

(You can also *prove* it by induction, after you *discover* it by some other means.)